# Convert ndarray of ndarrays to ndarray of digits

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to prepare my data for training and I need to get ndarray of shape `(20248, 1856)`.
For now i gathered all my data in `x` but i messed up somewhere and fixing it + running it over would take much computational time.
So my problem is that `x` has shape `(20248,)` and `x[0]` has shape `(1856,)`.
How can I convert it to `(20248, 1856)`?

Comment: Try `np.stack(x)`.  Either it works, or it throws an error complaining that the (sub) arrays must all be the same shape.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you! It works.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you can just do

```
np.array(x)
```

Source: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array

Comment: If it's already an array, calling `np.array` won't change the shape or 'nesting'.